# If an infinite set of sets $\{A_1,A_2,\dots\}$ satisfies the finite intersection property, then $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_i\neq\emptyset$?

Tags: general-topology

Motivation: I read that compact subsets of metric spaces have this property, and I was wondering why this is not true for all topological spaces.

If $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_i$, then there is at least one pair of sets $A_k,A_l$ such that $A_k\bigcap A_l=\emptyset$. If there is no such pair of disjoint sets, then a point $x$ is present in every set $A_i$, and hence in $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_i$.

By the finite intersection property, $A_k\bigcap A_l\neq\emptyset$ for any pair of sets. Hence, $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_i\neq\emptyset$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, if $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_i = \varnothing$, there need not be two disjoint sets in the family. Consider $A_i = (0,\, 1/i) \subset \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Sorry this was an exceedingly stupid question. I just found a flaw in my own argument. If there are no disjoint pairs, that does not imply one single point $x$ is included in all sets. There may be different points in intersections of different pairs of sets. So the intersection of all sets need not contain that one point. Thanks.

Comment: Wikipedia article on [Cantor intersection's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_intersection_theorem) mentions that: *On the other hand, both the sequence of open bounded sets $C_k = (0, 1/k)$ and the sequence of unbounded closed sets $C_k = [k, \infty)$ have empty intersection. All these sequences are properly nested.*

Answer (score 2):

Take the collection $A_i = (-\frac1{i},\frac1{i})\backslash \{0\}$. Its intersection is empty, but it has the required property...

Answer (score 1):

Let $$A_n=\{ n, n+1, n+2,... \} = \{ m \in \mathbb Z | m \geq n \}$$

Then, for any finite collection, the intersection is one of the sets (the one with the largest index), but the infinite intersection is the emptyset.